# Vertical alignment within a Bootstrap 4 column

Tags: bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

[image of the desired alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCVUH.jpg)I am trying to vertically align elements within a Bootstrap 4 column to its top and bottom. I know there are lots of answers to the problem already but nothing seems to be working in my case.
This is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-7">
      <h1>Product Name</h1>
      <h2>Product Description</h2>
      <a class="btn btn-lg header-btn btn-square" href="#">
          Datasheet
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-5">
      <img src="#">
   </div>
```

I want to align h1 and h2 elements to the top of the column (Product Name and Description), whereas Datasheet button element to the bottom of the column. 
This column shouldn't have a fixed size, it depends on the size of the image in "col-md-5".

I appreciate your help a lot. I had no success with Bootstrap Flex and Spacing utilities.

Comment: You need to add specific properties to elements inside the col-md-7

Comment: Could you please elaborate Aslam? I tried already Bootstrap margin utility classes "mb-0" on the button element as well as setting "col-md-7" to "display: flex" however I cannot achieve the desired effect.

Comment: The heading elements should be at the top of the column, whereas the button should be at the bottom. Under the link provided by Zim codeply.com/p/3umUPwCfXc everything seems to be vertically center aligned.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve: a full-screen container with child-elements align to top and bottom or something else?

Comment: I have added an image of the desired alignment in the problem description. I am trying to align a button element within Bootstrap 4 column to the bottom of the column. Both heading elements should stay at the top of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `col-md-7` also `display:flex` (`d-flex`) if you need to use flexbox alignment on its content...

https://www.codeply.com/p/3umUPwCfXc

```
<div class="col-md-7 d-flex flex-column">
        <h1>Product Name</h1>
        <h2>Product Description</h2>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg header-btn btn-square mt-auto" href="#"> Datasheet </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! It finally works! I highly appreciate it (many hours were spent on this).

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved